# Django Notification System

Tags: python, django

So i'm trying to build a notification system in django for my school project.

I wants to notify the user if someone has answered his question for which i'm doing something like this

```
answers = Answer.objects.filter(question__user=request.user).order_by('-id')
```

This is a simple way of notifying the user. Also, User will not know the new notifications they have received since last login.

Here's the model for Notification app,

```
class Notifs(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

In order to do that i'm trying something like this, i'm saving the last time when user have opened the notifications page & comparing this time with the time of answer. So, if user have received a answer since their last opening of page I wants to notify them.

In view i'm trying something like this,

```
def notifications(request):
new = Notifs.objects.filter(user=request.user)
if new:
    new.update(timestamp=timezone.now())
else:
    Notifs.objects.create(user=request.user, timestamp=timezone.now())

last_seen = ???
count = Answer.objects.filter(question__user=request.user, timestamp__gte=last_seen).count()
```

I don't know exactly how can i compare the time since user has opened the notification page & someone has answered his question since then. How can do that?

Please helpme. Thank You :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your answers model, make sure you have a field like this:

```
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

This will keep track of the time the new entries are created, and you don't need to do anything to set the field, as it will do it automatically.

Once you have that, and I'm assuming your `timestamp` field is to store the last time notifications were checked, you would do something like this:

```
last_checked = Notifs.objects.get(user=user).values_list('timestamp', flat=True)
```

To get the new notifications, you would do something like this:

```
answers = Answer.objects.filter(question__user=request.user, created__gte=last_checked).order_by('-id')
```

Comment: Sir, i'm getting an error, 'Notifs' object has no attribute 'values_list'. What should I do?

Comment: Try:  `Notifs.objects.values_list('timestamp', flat=True).get(user=user)`  I don't think that's the problem though.  It should be working.

Comment: Wow, Finally everything is working Perfectly fine! Thank you very much Sir @TimmSimpkins for your support by giving several helpful answers :)

Comment: One small change get(user=request.user) :)

Comment: I wasn't sure how you had the user stored, I assumed you would know that.

Comment: Everything is Fine Now. Thank You Sir :)

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have some suggestion regarding notification model design

```
class Notify:
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)  // User
   updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) // Which sets to time automatically when the objecct is last updated 
   read = models.BooleanField(default=False) // Which should be changed to true everytime user view the notification
```

**You need to import Q** and You can query unread notification of each user by something like this

```
Notifs.objects.filter(Q(user=user)&Q(read=False))
```